# UI Elements aren't visible by x:Name, they are visible only by Name. How to fix?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I can't get access to UI elements from code using `x:Name`. They are only available if I use simple `Name`. I need to restore the access by `x:Name` because it is necessary to use `FindName` method. The project was created before I started the work with it, that's why I can't know what could be done wrong before.

It's got the following namespace at the top of the window:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

Also, I suppose that code-behind was generated automatically, because it has the following message:

> THIS CODE AND INFORMATION ARE GENERATED BY AUTOMATIC CODE GENERATOR

I need to get access to pushpin. I added x:Name="push1" to it. But it is not visible from code-behind.

```
<maps:Map ZoomLevel="18" Height="575" Center="{Binding CurrentTopIssuesSchema.Coords, TargetNullValue=null}" Name="map1" Width="415" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,-10,0">
    <toolkit1:MapExtensions.Children>
        <toolkit1:Pushpin x:Name="push1" Background="{Binding CurrentTopIssuesSchema.StatusColor}" GeoCoordinate="{Binding CurrentTopIssuesSchema.Coords, TargetNullValue=null}" Content="{Binding CurrentTopIssuesSchema.Name}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Template_Content}">
        </toolkit1:Pushpin>
    </toolkit1:MapExtensions.Children> 
</maps:Map>
```

Here is namespaces from XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="WPAppStudio.View.TopIssues_Detail"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:ctl="clr-namespace:WPAppStudio.Controls"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:mytoolkit="clr-namespace:MyToolkit.Controls;assembly=MyToolkit.Extended"
xmlns:mytoolkitpaging="clr-namespace:MyToolkit.Paging;assembly=MyToolkit.Extended"
xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:WPAppStudio.Helpers"
xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
xmlns:toolkit1="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource CustomApplicationTextBrush}"
xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.WP.Controls.Layout;assembly=Syncfusion.SfTileView.WP8"
xmlns:Notification="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.WP.Controls.Notification;assembly=Syncfusion.SfHubTile.WP8"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
DataContext="{Binding Path=TopIssues_DetailViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
```

Metadata from code-behind:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
    using MyToolkit.Paging;
    using WPAppStudio.Ioc;
    using WPAppStudio.Localization;
    using WPAppStudio.Services.Interfaces;
    using WPAppStudio.ViewModel;
    using WPAppStudio.ViewModel.Interfaces;
    using WPAppStudio.Repositories.Interfaces;
    using Syncfusion.WP.Controls.Layout;
    using WPAppStudio.Entities;
    using WPAppStudio.Repositories.Base;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.IO;
    using WPAppStudio.Helpers;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Services;
    using System.Device.Location;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

    namespace WPAppStudio.View
    {
        /// 
        /// Phone application page for TopProducts_Detail.
        /// 
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGenerated]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("Radarc", "4.0")]
        public partial class TopIssues_Detail : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
            /// 
            /// Initializes the phone application page for TopProducts_Detail and all its components.
            /// 
            public TopIssues_Detail()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                if (Resources.Contains("PanoramaTopIssues_Detail0AppBar"))
                    PhonePage.SetApplicationBar(this, Resources["PanoramaTopIssues_Detail0AppBar"] as BindableApplicationBar);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it should be there see->http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758295.aspx

Comment: Do you see the control name you're looking for in the auto generated code?

Comment: @WiredPrairie, No, control has no name initially, there are no interactions with it from code. I want to add some of them using x:Name, but it fails.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include an example of an element and the code you want?

Comment: Likely: It's because the extension you're using doesn't add the children to the naming scope at all (and that's why it's not in the code behind). The `PushPin` isn't a normal child of a map control.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the following namespace is located at the top of your window:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

---

Also, make sure you're not specifying a `Name` *and* an `x:Name` value... only one or the other.

If you try to use both:

```
<DataGrid Name="dg" x:Name="dg2"></DataGrid>
```

Then in the code-behind, you will only be able to access it by the first one specified. (In this case, "dg".)

*(Trying to use both will prevent the project from compiling too.)*

Comment: exactly. Also, I suppose that code-behind was generated automatically, because there are "THIS CODE AND INFORMATION ARE GENERATED BY AUTOMATIC CODE GENERATOR" in code-behind.